# Python: Using kwargs with patch() decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, monkeypatching

**I can only use positional arguments with a function that uses `@patch`**. Running `being_patched(True)` works. Running `being_patched(arg=True)` does not.

The general principle is positional args cannot come after keyword args. I just find the the interaction with `@patch` to be unfortunate.

**Is there an alternative?**

I am running Python 3.11.

```
import traceback
from unittest.mock import patch
import os.path

@patch('os.path.isfile')
def being_patched(arg, isfile_mock):
    print(f"Inside being_patched. arg={arg}  isfile_mock={isfile_mock}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    being_patched(True)              # <== Works
    print("\n----------\n")
    try:
        being_patched(arg=True)      # <== Fails
    except TypeError:
        traceback.print_exc()
```

Produces this output:

```
Inside being_patched. arg=True  isfile_mock=<MagicMock name='isfile' id='3181488491344'>

----------

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mike Ulm\PycharmProjects\Exercises\USDataMap\patch_after_kwargs.py", line 13, in <module>
    being_patched(arg=True)
  File "C:\PythonFiles\Python311\Lib\unittest\mock.py", line 1375, in patched
    return func(*newargs, **newkeywargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
**TypeError: being_patched() got multiple values for argument 'arg'**
```

Running python 3.11

Comment: The Mock is going to be injected as the first unused positional argument. If you hand in `args` as a keyword argument, the Mock becomes the first positional argument `arg` and now you have `arg` twice.

Comment: Thanks for those details.  I can either 1) not use keywords or 2) not use patch decorators (e.g., using a with context manager).

I was wondering if someone with more experience or knowledge of Python had other options.

Comment: wish I could help with that, but just note the way to debug-print variables:
```py
print(f"{arg=} {isfile_mock=}")
```

Comment: Cool! That is a nice feature I had overlooked.  Thank you.

Comment: oh and to be clear it works with any expression, not just variable names `print(f"{3*4=}")`